# How to measure deltaTime?

Tags: c#, game-loop, timestep

I'm trying to make a simple console application and don't want to use Unity, but I want to implement a timer, so I would want to use Time.deltaTime.

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` is a Unity specific thing. If you want one in console application you can use a 3rd party lib or write your own. `Time.deltaTime` is calculated as time between frames, so if there are no frames and Unity engine is not running - the value probably won't be calculated. That is my assumption. Even if the value would be calculated it would be completely irrelevant value to console application.

Comment: Are you asking how to program a [tag:game-loop] and measure the time elapsed per frame? What have you tried, based on your research of existing guides and Q&A so far?

Answer (score 0):

## How to Measure deltaTime

It is measured by calling a timer every frame per second that holds the time between now and last call in milliseconds. Thereafter the resulting number (delta time) is used to calculate how far, for instance, a video game character would have travelled during that time.

### Basic implementation in Javascript

```js
let lastTime = performance.now(); // performance.now() returns the current timestamp
function gameLoop() {
    let now = performance.now();
    let deltaTime = now - lastTime;
    lastTime = now;
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it included code showing how to do that.